# Cross referencing data and removing entire lines that contain same string with Python

Tags: python, database, removing-whitespace, cross-reference

Cutting to the chase here...

I have 2 sets of data, both in .txt files.
We will call them **DATA A** and **DATA B**.

I am currently collecting information from other students for a mailing list / club application as well as gathering a bit more data from them. This data goes into **DATA A**. DATA A currently looks like the following example:

```
exampleemail@email.com | How many years in college: 3 | Address: 123 Example Blvd.
exampleemail2@email.com | How many years in college: 1 | Address: 444 Example Blvd.
exampleemail3@email.com | How many years in college: 2 | Address: 567 Example Blvd.
```

However, when people sign up at the auditorium and aren't monitored, they tend to only leave their email and leave out the certain pieces of information such as the following examples:

```
examplemail1@email.com | N/A | N/A
examplemail2@email.com | How many years in college: 1 | N/A
examplemail3@email.com | N/A | 111 Example Blvd.
```

When compiling both sets of data, I need to make sure that the semi-completed lines of data are (when both files are run with the script) still present on **DATA A**, but are in turn **REMOVED FROM DATA B** as to leave ONLY FRESH, NOT ALREADY PRESENT data on either **DATA B** or an **OUTPUT** file with ONLY THE EMAILS, not the blank data, so I can email them to ask for it...

Here is an example:

**EXAMPLE**

**DATA A**:

```
exampleemail@email.com | How many years in college: 3 | Address: 123 Example Blvd.
exampleemail2@email.com | How many years in college: 1 | Address: 444 Example Blvd.
exampleemail3@email.com | How many years in college: 2 | Address: 567 Example Blvd.
exampleemail4@email.com | How many years in college: 2 | Address: 888 Example Blvd.
```

**DATA B**:

```
exampleemail3@email.com | N/A | N/A
exampleemail1@email.com | How many years in college: 3 | N/A
exampleemail8@email.com | N/A | 888 Example Blvd.
examplemail12@email.com | N/A | N/A
```

+++ **SCRIPT IS RUN AT THIS POINT** +++
(Any COMMON data from DATA B is removed from DATA B OR an output file with only FRESH data is created)...

**OUTPUT**:

```
exampleemail8@email.com
examplemail12@email.com
```

Would love to know how to do this in Python - thanks!

Comment: first you have to learn Python, next start writing code, and when you get error message then come to Stackoverflow.

Comment: if you read emails from both files then you could convert them to `set()` and to `set(emails_B) - set(emails_A)` to get output

Comment: you could read files using `csv.reader` or `pandas.read_csv` with separator `|`